# Need some container in sencha gxt that can be similar to table in html

Tags: java, html, extjs, containers, gxt

I want to do the below thing.

Label1 : Value1                     Label2 : Value2 
Label3 : Value3                     Label4 : Value4

Now for doing the same using html i use to create a table with 7 columns and 2 rows so that all the elements are properly aligned.

How can i do the same using some container in Sencha gxt?

Comment: Try to use com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.Grid class.

Comment: But i do not want a grid. Isn't there some container like Horizontal Container or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the layout property that should also work in sencha gxt:

```
{
    xtype: 'container',
    layout: {
        type: 'table',
        columns: 7
    },
    items: [
       {
           html: 'Label1'
       },
       {
           html: ':'
       },
       {
           html: 'Value1',
       },
       {
           html: ''
           width: 50
       },
       {
           html: 'Label2'
       },
       {
           html: ':'
       },
       {
           html: 'Value2'
       },
       // next row
       {
           html: 'Label3'
       },
       {
           html: ':'
       },
       {
           html: 'Value3',
       },
       {
           html: ''
           width: 50
       },
       {
           html: 'Label4'
       },
       {
           html: ':'
       },
       {
           html: 'Value4'
       },
    ]
}
```

You are able to use colspan/rowspan on items if needed.

Here is a fiddle demo: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/fja